# Unknown error: cannot focus element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

Here is the input field code:

```
<span ng-if="cell.state != 'edit_mode'" class="ng-scope">
    <span ng-class="{'with-right-padding' : cell.input_type === 'auto_complete'}" class="value-cell ng-binding">10        </span>
    <!-- ngIf: cell.valid === false && server_side_errors_present -->
</span>
```

What i used is below:

```
//click on the field
element(by.xpath("//div[@class='animate']/div/div[2]/span[2]/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/span/section/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/section[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[3]/span/span[1]/span")).click();
//enter the value
element(by.xpath("//div[@class='animate']/div/div[2]/span[2]/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/span/section/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/section[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[3]/span/span[1]/span")).sendKeys("10");
```

Problem is when replay my code click event is works but send key is not working.

Below is the error i got:

```
Failures:
1) Customer Add a estimate
  Message:
    Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element
      (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17'
    System info: host: 'Bala-PC', ip: , os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\Bala\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4612_146}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=48.0.2564.109, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
    Session ID: e5f4a8ca6076e1cafbcc366f45680dd1


  Stack:
    UnknownError: unknown error: cannot focus element
      (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17'
    System info: host: 'Bala-PC', ip: '192.168.1.22', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\Bala\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4612_146}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=48.0.2564.109, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
```

Please someone give me solution.

Comment: Are you using the latest selenium driver? Certain versions of chrome driver have also been known to not work with the send keys function.

Comment: Yes, am using latest. What should i do now ?. But in other textbox it works

Comment: Have you tried it in FF and IE? Is the "other textbox" of the same element type?

Comment: Its actually not a textbox... my web application is Angularjs based. When u hit enter or double click on the field then it will give you a text area where you can enter a value....Below is the code snippet of the that field i took it from firebug... kindly check

<span ng-if="cell.state != 'edit_mode'" class="ng-scope">
        <span ng-class="{'with-right-padding' : cell.input_type === 'auto_complete'}" class="value-cell ng-binding">
          2
        </span>
        <!-- ngIf: cell.valid === false && server_side_errors_present -->
      </span>

Comment: The other textbox should actually be either input or textarea, look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='animate']/div/div[2]/span[2]/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/span/section/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/section[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[3]/span/span[1]/span"))
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", element, '10');
```

This might do the trick. This is basically using the execute script method from selenium webdriver... If this doesnt work, I would really advise trying to test the field by using something other than xpath. I think the difficulty is in focusing on the field

Answer (score 1):

The answer above uses javascript and will not work if the input or its parent has event handlers that need to be triggered, e.g. in case of type-ahead controls.

In order to fix it, we can use Selenium Actions:

```
Actions assigner = new Actions(webdriver);
assigner.moveToElement(webelement);
assigner.click();
assigner.sendKeys("<your value>");
assigner.build().perform();
```